# Pod update command returns error in cocoapod 1.0.0

Tags: ios, iphone, git, terminal, cocoapods

I updated my cocoapod version to 1.0.0.In my podfile containing many libraries and I want update libraries using **pod update** command.After running this command i got the message like this

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance
[!] /usr/bin/git fetch --unshallow

error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

My podfile content is like this

```
use_frameworks!

def myPods

    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'

end

target 'APP_DEV' do
    myPods
end

target 'APPTests' do
    myPods
end

target 'APPUITests' do
    myPods
end
```

How to solve this issue? Please help me

Comment: Can you add whole PODFile here? Which pods you have added!

Comment: I edited my question with podfile please go through it.

Comment: only one issue I found is `'` mark at `target ‘APPTests' do` left mark is different than right one. it's because of fonts.

Comment: oh that is my mistake..Now i again run the command Pod update then its working fine.Now all pods updated.Thank you